# How to sort in MongoDB collection by using the detail from other collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting

Suppose there are 2 collections having documents as following-

```
User
     {
      _id: ObjectId('a1234')
      name: 'Java'
     }
Records    
     {
      _id: ObjectId(bnbn123),
      userID: ObjectId('a1234'),
      items: 'book'
     }
```

Now I want to sort the 'Records' collection documents by using the 'name' presented in other(User) collection. How to do this in mongodb.

We can achieve it by using joins in sql, but not getting the idea to do it in mongodb.

For ex: to sort the Records by using items field:

db.Records.find().sort('items':1)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with SQL or MySQL, so you should remove those tags.

Comment: Do you have access to change the structure?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do that in MongoDB. You need to address the problem in other ways. Here are some options:

- Change the collection structures the way to include the detail from `User` to `Record`. However this will lead you to handling something like cascade update on client side.
- Do the sorting in the client code